# Algoritmo em C loop de for repetindo resposta

Tags: c, algoritmo, programação-estruturada

Pessoal estou cursando faculdade e travei em um exercicio da lista, é um algoritmo em C, poderiam me ajudar

Meu problema é que eu coloco um numero para servir a variavel x e ela calcula umas 4 vezes de maneira adequada, os números saem diferentes, depois o resultado sai todo igual, ate dar o loop 10 vezes, obrigado pela ajuda

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  float x, m, e, h, y, n, f, b, l, k, w;
  int s;
  printf(“Digite um valor para o angulo em radiano\ n”);
  scanf("%f", & x);
  w = 0;
  k = 0;
  y = 0;
  h = 1;
  f = 0;
  for (s = 1; s <= 8; s++) {

    b = s % 2;

    /*Colocar o valor positivo e negativo usando o if*/
    if (b == 0) {
      w = w + 2;
      y = pow(x, w);
      y = y * (-1);
    } else {
      w = w + 2;
      y = pow(x, w);
      y = y * 1;
    }

    /*Calculo do fatorial*/
    k = 1;
    f = f + 2;
    m = f;
    for (; m > 0; m = m - 1)
      k = m * k;

    /*resultado final*/
    h = y / k + h;
    printf("%f\n", h);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: olá, as variáveis podem ter nomes mais significativos, por exemplo "valor", "calculo", "angulo", etc.. `float x, m, e, h, y, n, f, b, l, k, w;` isso aqui é bem bizarro e ruim de ler :) olhando para esse monte de variáveis não consigo entender o propósito delas, fica até difícul ajudar. Ah, essa linha `for (; m > 0; m = m - 1)` ficaria melhor assim `for (m = f; m > 0; m--)`

Comment: Você não apresentou os valores utilizados nos testes mas aqui `h = y / k + h;` dependendo do valor de `k` (que é `f!`) o resultado da divisão pode tender a zero e para efeitos significativos não interferir no valor de `h`.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, percebi que seu código tem algumas redundâncias, por exemplo comandos iguais dentro do if e no else, variáveis não utilizadas e não incluiu a biblioteca matemática para usar a função pow, aconselho arrumar isto. Não entendi o propósito do seu programa, mas percebi que a repetição de resultados iguais é devido a falta de precisão nas casas decimais, ou seja, os últimos resultados diferem em uma grandeza menor que 10^-6 e por isso não é possível perceber que são diferentes já que o float mostra até 6 casas decimais, se multiplicar o resultado em Y é notável isso

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main() {
  double x, m, h, y, f, b, k, w;
  int s;
  printf("Digite um valor para o angulo em radiano\n\t");
  scanf("%lf", &x);
  w = 0;
  k = 0;
  y = 0;
  h = 1;
  f = 0;
  for (s = 1; s <= 8; s++) {

b = s % 2;

/*Colocar o valor positivo e negativo usando o if*/

w = w + 2;
y = pow(x, w);

if (b == 0) {
  y = y * (-1);
}

/*Calculo do fatorial*/
k = 1;
f = f + 2;

for (m=f ; m > 0; m--){
    k = m * k;
}


/*resultado final*/
h = 1000000000*y / k + h;
printf("%lf\n", h);
}return 0;}
```